# number lines in a file

Tags: text-processing, numbering

So I have a file `text.txt`  with lines of some characters
example:

```
abc    
abc
yxz
abc
```

now I would like to number the lines like this and copy it to another file.

End expected result:

```
1  abc
2  abc 
3  yxz
4  abc
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of utilities to number lines on Unix, but quite annoyingly they don't do *only* the basic numbering by default.

`nl file` is the (Unix/GNU, not POSIX) command to number the lines of a file, but it only numbers non-empty lines by default and processes special footer/header page delimiter by default. To get it to number all lines, you'd need to do:

```
nl -ba -d '
' text.txt > newfile
```

(that's a newline character inside single quotes above), but even [that doesn't work with some `nl` implementations](https://groups.google.com/g/comp.unix.shell/c/cxM02TRRFPg/m/JpaD5LzlBQAJ).

Among POSIX commands, we also have `pr`:

```
pr -tn5 text.txt > newfile
pr -t:n5 text.txt > newfile
```

Though it will treat the form feed character specially.

```
awk '{printf "%5d %s\n", FNR, $0}' text.txt > newfile
```

should be OK and lets you format the number whichever way you want, like for your *expected output*:

```
awk '{printf "%-2d %s\n", FNR, $0}' text.txt > newfile
```

Also:

```
grep -n '^' text.txt > newfile
```

with yet another different output format.

Some `cat` implementations also support `-n` for that:

```
cat -n text.txt > newfile
```

Comment: awk '{printf "%5d %s\n", FNR, $0}' file  <--- this is the jackpot, thank you for help !!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you want (since you said you want to order the file, but the output you gave has the exact same order as the input), but to enumerate lines you can use `nl`.

`nl filename > outputfile`

Comment: Note that by default `nl` only numbers the non-empty lines (it also handles special sequences to mean header/footer...).